# Cols Steele Yelp Camp project, cluster maps not showing campgrounds

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

The code below, doesnt work. I have done everything as at the Lesson!!!

```
  <script>
        const mapToken = '<%=process.env.MAPBOX_TOKEN%>';
        const campgrounds = { features: <%= JSON.stringify(campgrounds) %>};
  </script>
```

Throws this Error!

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '&' (at campgrounds:199:55)
clusterMap.js:1  Uncaught ReferenceError: mapToken is not defined
    at clusterMap.js:1:24
```

please help somebody!!!!

i dont know how to fix or how to try to fix it!

Answer (score 1):

You're using `<%=` instead of the unescaped value `<%-`

Your line should look like this.

```
const campgrounds = { features: <%- JSON.stringify(campgrounds) %>};
```

Answer (score 0):

const campgrounds = `{ features: <%- JSON.stringify(campgrounds) %>};`
this worked for me, i found that my vscode after i pressed save, was saving so:

`const campgrounds = { features: <% - JSON.stringify(campgrounds) %>};` and that is the reason of error! so stupid!:D